discrepancy when do async calls for page render with two inputs
I am using pdfjs and pdf-lib for rendering pdf fetching from ajax call. this is where I get bytes from pdfDoc, set numNumPages and setModifiedPdfBytes.
 useEffect(() => {
        if (pdfBytes == null) return;
        async function modifyAllPages(pdfBytes) {
            try {
                const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes);
                
                
                const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();

                //....rest of logic

                const modifiedPdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
                return modifiedPdfBytes;
            } catch (error) {
                throw new Error('Error modifying PDF: ' + error.message);
            }
        }

        async function handleModification() {
            try {
                // Calculate the number of pages synchronously
                const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes);
                const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
                setNumPages(pages.length);

                // Modify the pages asynchronously
                const modifiedPdfBytes = await modifyAllPages(pdfBytes);
                setModifiedPdfBytes(modifiedPdfBytes);
                console.log('Modified PDF bytes:', modifiedPdfBytes);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error.message);
            }
        }

        handleModification();.
    }, [pdfBytes, pdfCryptoInfo]);

and this is where I render it
  return (
      <>
          <div>{base64PdfString}</div>
          <div>{numPages}</div>
          {
              base64PdfString && (
                  <div ref={setContainerRef}>
                      {Array.from({ length: numPages || 0 }, (_, index) => index + 1).map((pageNumber) => (
                          <div
                              key={pageNumber}
                              style={{
                                  marginRight: '10px', // Adjust spacing between pages
                                  marginBottom: '10px', // Adjust spacing between pages
                                  display: 'flex',
                                  flexDirection: 'column',
                                  alignItems: 'center'
                              }}
                          >
                              {/* Render each page conditionally based on the current page */}
                              <PageRenderer
                                  pageNumber={pageNumber}
                                  base64PdfString={base64PdfString}
                                  containerWidth={containerWidth}
                              />
                          </div>
                      ))}
                  </div>
          )}
      </>
  );

I render twice successively for two pdf doc input. In second call it sees numPages of previous call.
How to consistently pass paramters both base64PdfString and numPages consistently?
I tried this:
        // Modify the pages asynchronously
        const modifiedPdfBytes = await modifyAllPages(pdfBytes);
        setModifiedPdfBytes(modifiedPdfBytes); //added this line  for make it sync.

